# Can't set ListActivity ID in Android Studio Properties Designer

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a ListActivity and need to have the ID be: @android:id/list

When using the graphical designer in Android Studio I am not able to give the above name in the ID as it requires only characters be entered.  In order for this to work I have to enter the above name in the XML directly.  I know that is not the case with Eclipse.  Should I not be able to enter the above ID through the properties in the graphical designer?